# Who was the noble present at the Tennis Court Oath?

Tags: france, 18th-century, french-revolution

I remember learning that a member of the 2nd Estate was notably present at the [Tennis Court Oath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_Court_Oath) (though I realize there might have been more than one).

Does anyone know who that might have been?

Also, on a side note, is it true that the location was actually a handball court?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Some context would help this question a lot.

Comment: The Tennis Court was an indoor tennis court, and thus most likely played with rules for Royal Tennis, a variant different from the lawn tennis we are familiar with today. From David's sketch, it certainly looks as though hand ball could have been played there.

Comment: Update: While studying for AP Euro I realized which member of the 2nd Estate I was talking about in this question: Count Mirabeau. While it's possible that Lafayette was there as well, Mirabeau is the noble whom I learned was notably present at the Tennis Court Oath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One noble present at the Tennis Court Oath was the Marquis de Lafayette. He had been schooled in the American Revolution, and was about to embark on the French Revolution.

Comment: Sorry about that - I meant the 2nd Estate. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Do you have sources for this answer?

Comment: @Luke: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Constituent_Assembly. Here is a "modern" source. But I actually learned this fact reading about Lafayette in grade school.